# Value cannot be null. Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have web API

I try to send request from postman

Here is my Model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace trackingappbackend.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class StartWorkingDay
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string INN { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is controller

```
// POST: api/StartWorkingDays
    [ResponseType(typeof(StartWorkingDay))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostStartWorkingDay(StartWorkingDay startWorkingDay)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.StartWorkingDays.Add(startWorkingDay);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = startWorkingDay.Id }, startWorkingDay);
    }
```

I pass data like on screen

[image]

But I have this error

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity

How I can fix it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't think this is the right dublicate. It seems to be a deserialization issue.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree with NtFreX

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Please have look into your model and then your database which parameter should not pass as a null and hopefully that will provide you the path.

Comment: It's id, but I generate it automatically @Rughaani

Comment: Please fill the actual date and time in your request. **Date = sdf , Time = sdfsdf is incorrect**.

Comment: It's in string @Rughaani

Comment: Updated my post@mjwills

Comment: In the postman choice the Raw radio selection then application/json.

Comment: In raw all okay @Rughaani

Comment: Also show us the `Headers` tab from Postman. A screenshot please.

Comment: please provide your WebApiConfig.cs code and what is your controller name??

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the data in the request body and your Post method doesn't know that. You can change your Post method to add [FromBody] to extract the data from the body.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(StartWorkingDay))]
public IHttpActionResult PostStartWorkingDay([FromBody]StartWorkingDay startWorkingDay)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.StartWorkingDays.Add(startWorkingDay);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = startWorkingDay.Id }, startWorkingDay);
}
```

also, try to debug your method to see if your startWorkingDay parameter is deserialized with the data sent.

Hope that helpes.

Omar